# Creating a good question: Feedback along with Close votes?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, close-review-queue

I find on Ask Ubuntu that I answer questions better than I ask them. No big issue, it is something that I am working on. So when I create a question I put a lot of thought into it, witness this Q&A effort here:

[WinFF: Preset to convert to H.265/HEVC under Xenial Xerus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/792200/57576)

For this question I found a gap in Xenial Xerus: FFmpeg can produce hevc files but WinFF *cannot* as it does not have a suitable preset. With a little research I produced a good preset, tested the installation and running of the preset and finally created the Q&A.

A couple of Close votes came in and this is fine, I am more than happy to listen and be guided by Community needs and I have altered my question to make it both clearer and less broad as suggested. A comment left after the question outlines this for the benefit of others looking through the Close review queue.

But what I am after with this question is this:

> Consider leaving some constructive comments intended to guide a
>   question along a better path *along with* your Close vote. This will
>   be particularly effective with those question writers who have perhaps
>   been with Ask Ubuntu for a while and who are probably keen to produce
>   a good quality question which will enhance the site...

Such feedback in Comment form would *certainly* have guided me along in fine tuning my own question and I suspect that this is probably true of many other questions asked on Ask Ubuntu.

That is all :).

Comment: I stupidly misread your question (close votes <> down votes, obviously too early in the morning). Be it very brief (a single line), the *reason* for close voting gives you *some* information though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Indeed it does, and certainly in my own case this was enough. Mind you there is still a little guess work involved...

Comment: edited my answer :)

Comment: Don't worrie too much about a couple of close votes, bad votes are cast all the time. I add things I find in to Q&A here and it can be hard to reverse engineer an answer in to a question and do it clearly, within the scope of the site. FWIW I don't think your question is `too broad`, in fact it is quite specific, or `unclear` as you clearly want a WinFF preset. Even if it gets closed (I don't think it will) you can always vote to reopen.

Comment: @MarkKirby I think that "bad votes" aren't cast all the time. I think that no votes are done all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasons for close voting gives you at least *some* information on why. I can understand you'd like to have more information, however:

Reviewing is quite a burden to the site. We already have a continuously growing stack of items in queue, until someone decides to do, or calls for, a clean up.
I really don't think it is realistic to ask people to write a constructive comment while reviewing. It may sound silly, but continuously *switching* from a "judging" mode to decide, into a *communicative* mode to comment and back, that simply is a too demanding process to go through, looking at the amounts that have to pass the review.

Having said that, of course it is always a good idea to give a constructive comment if you run into a question that can be "saved". It is better to edit into a good question then to close while a small edit could have made the difference.
In practice, this will be *occasionally* rather then part of the procedure however.

Comment: A great balanced view, thanks @Jacob Vlijm :)